# Android Kotlin Volley upload image and post other values at the same time?

Tags: android, post, kotlin, android-volley, image-uploading

I am using the code in this tutorial
[Upload an Image or File to Your Server Using Volley in Kotlin](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-upload-an-image-file-to-your-server-using-volley-in-kotlin-a-step-by-step-tutorial-23f3c0603ec2)

The code works I can upload an image but I also need to post other values together with the image in the same request.
Following is the code which perform the upload. How do I add the other post values to the request?

```
private fun uploadImage() {
    imageData?: return
    val request = object : VolleyFileUploadRequest(
        Method.POST,
        postURL,
        Response.Listener {
            println("response is: $it")
        },
        Response.ErrorListener {
            println("error is: $it")
        }
    ) {
        override fun getByteData(): MutableMap<String, FileDataPart> {
            var params = HashMap<String, FileDataPart>()
            params["imageFile"] = FileDataPart("image", imageData!!, "jpeg")
            return params
        }
    }
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("api_token", "gh659gjhvdyudo973823tt9gvjf7i6ric75r76");
                params.put("name", mNameInput.getText().toString());
                params.put("location", mLocationInput.getText().toString());
                params.put("about", mAvatarInput.getText().toString());
                params.put("contact", mContactInput.getText().toString());
                return params;
            }
```

Comment: The code is in java not kotlin but the idea is correct. Thanks!